# Using Graphics.copyArea with transparent image

Tags: java, graphics

I'm trying to shift a portion of an image, currently using g.copyArea(). It works fine with solid colors, but the transparent pixels aren't being copied (because they're transparent!). I want to make the color underneath transparent.

This image shows what's happening, if a start shape was copied, but I want the whole area to copy, overwriting the all pixels below.

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3f4b8888b0.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/3f4b8888b0.png)

This is what I want:

[alt text http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ee911ea35a.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/ee911ea35a.png)

```
BufferedImage b;
...    
Graphics g = b.getGraphics();
g.copyArea(x,y,w,h,dx,dy);
```

I have considered copying the image to another image, clearing the orginal image then copy it back to the new position, but there must be a better way?

Disclaimer: This is *part* of a homework project.

Comment: Actually I do think this is a good homework question.  Specific, to the point, only a problematic part and you showed that you tried before. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src), like so:

```
Graphics2D g;
...
g.setComposite(AlphaComposite.Src)
g.copyArea(x,y,w,h,dx,dy);
```

Thanks to unwind for suggesting the use of Graphics2D.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you should be using Graphics? I think it is semi-deprecated, and you're supposed to use [Graphics2D](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html) nowadays.

With `Graphics2D` you can set the background color, which might help to prevent the unwanted transparency.